# Powering multiple Pis and HDDs -- reducing number of power plugs used to run my devices and Raspberry Pis

Tags: power-supply

I have two Raspberry Pis with an external 3.5" HDD connected to each. They're taking up 4x sockets on a power strip underneath my TV. A few of which are wall warts with a USB plug on the end outputting 5V 2A.

1. Would a powered USB multi-charger like this be suitable to power all the devices? Therefore reducing the number of sockets used. [USB power charger with multiple sockets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IBDOB5I)
2. Could I use a USB to barrel jack adapter to power the HDDs?
3. Can I power other devices like my Logitech Home Hub by the aforementioned USB charger.

The USB power charger would be for powering devices only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anker's multi-port USB chargers are fantastic and I use the 10-port version myself. The item you linked in your point 1 is an old item, the new version is a [6-port 60W USB charger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WI2DN4S). Just keep in mind that 60W means 12A times 5V, and all ports share those Amps. So the fewer devices you have plugged in, the more Amps they can pull. That said, with 60W you should be able to give 6 devices 2A each, or better, 4 devices can each get up to 3A, which should be enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Do you think the USB to barrel jack adapter would work for powering the external HDDs?

Comment: Not knowing the specifics of the adapter you're looking at I would say "yes", as the adapter is a passive device - it just changes the presentation of the positive and ground terminals on the USB plug into a barrel format.

Comment: @juliushibert most hdd enclosures require a voltage greater than 5v(the USB maximum) but instead need 12 which your USB hub wouldn't be able to power.

Comment: @juliushibert no problem, next time be sure to tag the person you are replying to by placing an @ sign followed by their name before their comment

Comment: @PhilB. As I understand then, it would be more stable, in terms of power, to get a 6-port USB charger that does 12A and 60W than a 10-port USB charger with the same 12A and 60W power specs. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think it'll make much difference, as long as you plug in only 6 devices in each of them.